# Python: How to change and .apply function into a .loc function

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, apply

I have a data frame and a function that I tried to apply on the data frame. The data frame looks like this:

|  | commodity_name | last_trading_date | volume | new_window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | oil | 2021-04-30 | 29000 | Jun 21 |
| 102 | oil | 2021-05-31 | -21000 | Jul 21 |
| 168 | gold | 2021-01-29 | -3000 | Feb 21 |
| 170 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -3 | Q1 21 |
| 272 | oil | 2020-12-31 | -17000 | Q1 21 |
| 298 | gold | 2021-04-30 | 2400 | May 21 |
| 309 | oil | 2021-02-26 | -12000 | Q2 21 |
| 460 | api2coal | 2021-02-26 | 11000 | Q1 21 |
| 496 | api2coal | 2021-06-30 | -16000 | Jul 21 |
| 504 | gold | 2021-02-26 | -1300 | Mar 21 |
| 535 | oil | 2020-11-30 | -17000 | Cal 21 |
| 622 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -3 | Cal 21 |
| 657 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -14 | Cal 21 |
| 704 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -7 | Cal 21 |
| 934 | czpower | 2020-12-30 | -10 | Cal 21 |
| 1208 | oil | 2021-01-29 | -21000 | Q1 21 |
| 1257 | czpower | 2020-12-30 | -25 | Q1 21 |
| 1388 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -12 | Cal 21 |
| 1424 | oil | 2021-04-30 | 11000 | Jun 21 |
| 1499 | oil | 2021-04-30 | 9000 | Jun 21 |
| 1635 | gold | 2021-03-31 | 1500 | Apr 21 |
| 1815 | api2coal | 2021-04-30 | 18000 | May 21 |
| 1818 | oil | 2021-04-30 | 8000 | Jun 21 |
| 1821 | oil | 2021-02-26 | -5000 | Q2 21 |
| 1925 | depower | 2020-12-30 | -12 | Cal 21 |
| 1927 | czpower | 2021-05-31 | -8 | Jun 21 |
| 2188 | api2coal | 2021-04-30 | -20000 | May 21 |
| 2282 | oil | 2020-11-30 | 21000 | Cal 21 |
| 2297 | gold | 2021-04-30 | -800 | May 21 |
| 2312 | czpower | 2021-03-30 | -17 | Q2 21 |

and the function is the following:

```
def split_tenor(row):
    start, year = row['new_window'].split(" ")
    if start == "Cal":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
        year = int(year) + 1
    elif start == "Q1":
        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
    elif start == "Q2":
        months = ["Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    elif start == "Q3":
        months = ["Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
    elif start == "Q4":
        months = ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    else:
        return row['new_window'], row['volume']

    if start == "Cal":
        split_vol = [row['volume']/12] * 3 + [row['volume']/4] * 3
    else:
        split_vol = [row['volume']/len(months)] * len(months)
    
    return [f"{m} {year}" for m in months], split_vol
```

once applied to the data frame, it creates a new variable `new_volume` and updates the variable `new_window`. I call it and update the data frame using these commands:

```
df["new_window"], df["new_volume"] = zip(*df[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))

df = df.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
```

However, whenever I call it, it returns the following warning:

> /tmp/ipykernel_3460/2106681681.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume",
> "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
> /tmp/ipykernel_3460/2106681681.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value
> is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
> .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume",
> "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))

If I understand correctly, it suggests that I use the `.loc` function instead of the `.apply` function, but I don't know how to do that. Can someone please help do it. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

Some comments suggested that I replace:

```
split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
```

with

```
split_1[['new_window', 'new_volume']] = split_1.apply(split_tenor, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

And it gave me this error this time (`split_1` is the real name, not `df`).

```
Input In [20], in filter_function(bookcode, cpartycode, datecode)
     23 split_2 = filtered[filtered['last_trading_date'] >= datecode].copy()
     25 # Do the cascading to split_1
     26 
     27 # split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"] = zip(*split_1[["volume", "new_window"]].apply(split_tenor, axis = 1))
     28 
     29 # Change the line above
---> 31 split_1[['new_window', 'new_volume']] = split_1.apply(split_tenor, axis=1, result_type='expand')
     33 split_1 = split_1.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
     35 split_2['new_volume'] = split_2['volume']

File ~/sevencommodities/jupyterenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers/utils.py:428, in check_key_length(columns, key, value)
    426 if columns.is_unique:
    427     if len(value.columns) != len(key):
--> 428         raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
    429 else:
    430     # Missing keys in columns are represented as -1
    431     if len(columns.get_indexer_non_unique(key)[0]) != len(value.columns):

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: It is not suggesting to replace `apply`, its telling you that using `[]` as indexer when modifying the data is unsafe and you should use `.loc[]` instead

Comment: Do `df[['new_window', 'new_volume']] = df.apply(split_tenor, axis=1, result_type='expand')` instead of all that `zip` nonsense~

Comment: "If I understand correctly, it suggests that I use the .loc function instead of the .apply" no, that isn't what it is suggesting. The problem is (I think) due to `split_1["new_window"], split_1["new_volume"]  = ....`, I bet `split_1` was made doing something like `split1 = df[something]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes it was, `split_1` is already a subset of another larger data frame.

Comment: @BeRT2me I tried your solution, but it still gives the same warning.

Comment: Is it supposed to be an independent copy? Because then to avoid the warning just do `split = df[something].copy()`. Also consider the advice of @BeRT2me and dispense with the `df[x], df[y] = zip(*...)` and use `df[[x,y]] = ...` (although, that isn't related to the error, but that is the way you should be doing this)

Comment: Ye, mine doesn't solve/address the warning, it's just a much better way of doing things.

Comment: @BeRT2me Good. If I replace `df[x], df[y] = zip(*...)` with `df[[x,y]] = ...`, should I still keep the next line (`df = df.explode(["new_window", "new_volume"])
`) or remove it?

Comment: Yes, you'll still need to explode it like you did before.